# Refactoring a validation flow

Tags: c#, optimization, refactoring, standards

I have function that flows as follows below, where it will return null if something isn't right and I don't wish to continue. Otherwise it will continue on and eventually return the new object. Is there a more ideal flow/standard to this, or is it "acceptable". I would like to make it easier to read/understand.

```
        //Check if the account number is NOT null
        //All files have the account number in the filename.
        if (accountNumber == null)
            return null;

        //Determine the document type
        DocumentType docType = DetermineDocumentType(fileName);
        if (docType == DocumentType.ERROR)
            return null;

        //Open document with RTF Parser
        AP_Document newApDoc = parser.FindData(file, docType);
        if (newApDoc == null)
            return null;

        //Determine the delivery method by analyzing the "SendTo" field's contents.
        //TODO: Use fax number from file name?
        Tuple<DeliveryMethodType, string> result = DetermineDeliveryMethod(newApDoc.SendTo);
        if (result == null)
            return null;


        //Change the delivery method and update where it's going to.
        newApDoc.ChangeDeliveryType(result.Item1);
        newApDoc.SendTo = result.Item2;

        return newApDoc;
```

Comment: You might find it helpful to throw exceptions. The calling code can do what it will with them, but it's a lot easier to debug when code indicates precisely what condition failed. Tip: When you add code to generate an exception try asking yourself what your first question will be, e.g. if it says "fiddlesticks out of range" you'll likely wonder what is the range and what was the value. Add those to the exception!

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of taste but I believe that in your scenario, as @HABO commented, throwing exceptions would be better. Alternatively, you could also use or write a validation library (such as fluent validation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)) that returns some sort of validation report object which your code would use to determine if it wanted to continue in processing the object or then throw an exception. I think exceptions and a general restructuring of your code would be best here.

To me it seems your code is doing things from both higher and lower level contexts all in the one function. Maybe changing your code will help in the decision as to how you would structure your validation/processing code. A contrived rewrite of your code may look like below. It's not complete and probably containing too many nested exceptions but it gives you an idea of what is possible. Basically, I've broken the processing of the filename and the building of the document into different functions at the high level. By having the extra methods, you are able to replace the comments with method names that explain what's happening. It's by no means perfect  but it may give your a few ideas.

If it's a small app, this may be going overboard but being part of a bigger project, breaking things into smaller methods might help you see common behaviour that could become refactored into new classes. I hope this gives a different perspective - these things are always interesting to discuss and everyone has a different approach.

```
public ApDocument RetrieveApDocument(string filename) 
{
    try
    {
        var info = GetFileInfo(filename);
        var newApDoc = BuildNewDocument(info);

        return newApDoc;
    }
    catch(InvalidFilenameException ex)
    {
        // decide what to do
    }
    // maybe catch the file parsing errors here
}

private FileInfo GetFileInfo(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        var accountNumber = GetAccountNumber(filename);
        var docType = DetermineDocType(filename);

        return new FileInfo(accountNumber, docType);
    }
    catch(InvalidAccountNumberException ex)
    {
        // maybe log here or decide what to do next or not even catch these...
        throw new InvalidFilenameException("Filename: " + filename + " is not in the correct format", ex);
    }
    catch(InvalidDocumentTypeException ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidFilenameException("Filename: " + filename + " is not in the correct format", ex);
    }
}

private string GetAccountNumber(string filename) 
{
    // whatever you do here - throw exception when error occurs
}

private string DetermineDocType(string filename) 
{
    // whatever you do here - throw exception when error occurs
}

private ApDocument BuildNewDocument(FileInfo info)
{

    // try / catch here if need be
    var doc = parser.FindData(file, docType);

    // set your other 'SendTo' and DeliveryType stuff here.

    return doc;    
}
```